# Using external script in Views.py

Tags: python, django

I have a file that sends a request to an API and retrieves information. Let's call this file `get_info.py`.  I am now building a GUI that uses Django and the `views.py` file, with methods 'GET' and 'POST'.

I am now importing the function from `get_info.py` into `views.py` and using it as follows

````
from get_info import get_info
@api_view(['GET'])
def generate_route(request):
    """
    :param request:
    1. lat: posx
    2. lng: pos,
    3. r: radius in km
    4. strategy,
    5. edge_num,
    6. deep,
    :return:
    """
    posx = request.query_params.get('lat', None)
    posy= request.query_params.get('lng', None)

    r= request.query_params.get('r', None)
    strategy = request.query_params.get('strategy', None)
    strategy = strategy if strategy else 3
    edge_num = request.query_params.get('edge_num', None)
    edge_num = edge_num if edge_num else 3
    deep = request.query_params.get('deep', None)
    deep = deep if deep else 3
    print("BEFORE", posx, posy, r, strategy, edge_num, deep)
    route = get_info(posx, posy, r)
    print("AFTER", route)
    if request.query_params.get('lat', None) is not None \
            and request.query_params.get('lng', None) is not None \
            and request.query_params.get('r', None) is not None:
        return Response({}, status=status.HTTP_200_OK)
    else:
        return Response({
            "Error": 'Need lat, lng, and r {}'.format(request.query_params.get('lat', None))
        }, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```
````

However, I get the response

```
> (u'BEFORE', u'112.34', u'14.55', u'300.3', 3, 3, 3)
  Internal Server Error: /app/api/v1/get_info/
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 41, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 249, in _legacy_get_response
    response = self._get_response(request)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 187, in _get_response
    response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 185, in _get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/views/decorators/csrf.py", line 58, in wrapped_view
    return view_func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/views/generic/base.py", line 68, in view
    return self.dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/rest_framework/views.py", line 483, in dispatch
    response = self.handle_exception(exc)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/rest_framework/views.py", line 443, in handle_exception
    self.raise_uncaught_exception(exc)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/rest_framework/views.py", line 480, in dispatch
    response = handler(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/rest_framework/decorators.py", line 53, in handler
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/user/Projects/app/views.py", line 750, in generate_route
    route = get_info(posx, posy, r)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/views/decorators/csrf.py", line 58, in wrapped_view
    return view_func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/views/generic/base.py", line 68, in view
    return self.dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/rest_framework/views.py", line 466, in dispatch
    request = self.initialize_request(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/rest_framework/views.py", line 370, in initialize_request
    parser_context=parser_context
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/rest_framework/request.py", line 159, in __init__
    .format(request.__class__.__module__, request.__class__.__name__)
AssertionError: The `request` argument must be an instance of `django.http.HttpRequest`, not `__builtin__.unicode`.
```

But when I use `from django.http import HttpRequest` to build my request, it tells me 'maximum depth exceeded'.

The `get_info` method is quite long, but in a nutshell it looks like this:

```
def get_info(posx, posy, r, strategy=3, edge_num=0.8, deep=0):  
    req_url = "http://api.map.baidu.com/direction/v2/driving?origin=posx..."
    trip = requests.get(req_url).json()
    return trip
```

When I run this `get_info` method in my python shell, it returns the desired trip.

Comment: `route = get_info(posx, posy, r)` line causes the exception. Can you include `get_info()` ?

Comment: Included it. It's very long but that should show you the gist of it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you look closely rest framework is the one which is causing the problem, If the getinfo is an APIView then it might need request as its first argument not posx which is a string.

Comment: I tried changing the argument to get_info as get_info(request) and it tells me: `AssertionError: The 'request' argument must be an instance of 'django.http.HttpRequest', not 'rest_framework.request.Request`.

Comment: This is strange, can you show the function signature and decorators if any

Comment: function signature and decorators of `get_info`? well, it doesn't have any decorators (maybe it should?) and the signature is that all the arguments are floats.

Comment: try passing request._request to get_info and see if that fixes the issue.

Comment: Hmmm.. that tells me:

...  
```File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/views/generic/base.py", 
line 68, in view
    return self.dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/rest_framework/views.py", line 
466, in dispatch
    request = self.initialize_request(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/rest_framework/views.py", line 
370, in initialize_request
    parser_context=parser_context
RuntimeError: maximum recursion depth exceeded
[25/Jul/2018 12:30:30]```

Comment: That would mean the private request attr might be the request itself and calling itself over and over again. You can either lookup how to extract django http from rest http. Or change your code to function much smoothly. Calling another view while inside a view doesnt seem like a good pattern to me. You could consider extracting logic to its own classes and using views as tools to deliver response

Comment: Well, not sure if this is standard practice, but I just added the `api_view` decorator into the `get_info.py` file method directly, and used that in my urls.  Hope this doesn't disrupt the clean code universe lol.